# How to map an array of object with nested objects and join the values together in the final result

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I'm trying to map an array of objects which has nested objects and the final result should be a new object with a key and the values joined together

For example, below the snippets

```js
const res = [{
  criteria: {
    min: "25",
    max: "100"
  }
}, {
  criteria: {
    min: 0,
    max: "85"
  },
}, {
  criteria: {
    min: "10",
    max: "85"
  },
}, ].map(
  (e) => ({
    valid: e.criteria
  })
)

console.log(res)
```

That map resulting in this way

```
[
  {
    "valid": {
      "min": "25",
      "max": "100"
    }
  },
  {
    "valid": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": "85"
    }
  },
  {
    "valid": {
      "min": "10",
      "max": "85"
    }
  }
]
```

My goal is the following result

```
[
  {
    "valid": ["25 - 100"]
  },
  {
    "valid": ["0 - 85"]
  },
  {
    "valid": ["10 - 85"]
  }
]
```

I don't know how to make it happen and also criteria can come like `criteria: null`
The cases are as above we can have both min and max in one obj or have one object with only min or max and one obj with just null.

What could be the best way to achieve my goal that I don't know

**UPDATE**
Some of the information changed as the data coming into this stage was modified to one clear.

The issue with previous coming data is that when min or max was 0 was removed and that causes issue further in the system.

As that has been correct by a colleague the cases are as follow

1. criteria: min: 0 max: "10" it is valid and will result as ["0 - 10"]
2. criteria: min: 1000 max: 0 will give an error so no present in data

What will be never in data min or max as alone values

Comment: Your expected output structure loses detail, how do we know that `"valid": ["85"]` is a min or a max?.   Wouldn't  `"valid": [" - 85"]` make more sense.?

Comment: @Keith the `valid` property of the final result is supposed to be the interval between min and max and there's no loss of information.

Comment: That is no need as wherever is min or max I have to join the 2 numbers with a join and dash. The numbers are never negative and are always from 0 to a number.
It is a range always, never negative numbers

Comment: @Jakub the snippet you shared on top has a malformed object definition and throws error if you took the time to try it before sharing. By the way to get your final result just run a further map on your resulted output returning for each item an array containing a single string composed as min-max (still confused why you chose an array and not just a string directly)

Comment: I tried and was working gonna edit maybe I did something wrong before saving and post

Comment: The reason are requirements I have that why is not a string but a [""] not sure fully myself but I was told to make it in this way

Comment: @diegod  Still not clicking with me,  So if I gave you `"valid": ["40"]`,  is that a min or max?.  So for me the OP is losing if that number is a min or a max, not sure what you mean by interval as the OP doesn't mention this.

Comment: @Jakub  `never negative numbers`,  That's not what my comment was implying, `- 80` would mean max 80, were as `10 - ` would imply min 10.  I'm maybe missing something really simple, but the fact the number is either a min or max, that detail has been lost in your output, if that detail is not important, then fair enough..

Comment: @Keith... yes I didn't correctly get your point before.. a string composed like that actually loose the information if it was min or max. My objection was wrong

Comment: honestly, I don't understand that but data is coming in that way after being validated in their steps of the system. When we have both min and max will never be a min > max as that was validated before and always both will be present with a number. Always will be min and max with a number, min or max with a number, or will be null if boh has no number. Cannot be ever min: "" max: "10" as min will be removed from validation and you only get max: "10"

I gonna edit my question to give  a detail on it

Comment: @Jakub  Unfortunately your edit hasn't helped. :(  The data coming in looks pretty logical to me, no problem there.  The part I'm talking about is your output..  eg.  say `'['40']`  what does this now mean, is it min 40, or max 40, the only thing we can say is that the number 40 is valid,  41? or 39?  we don't know as we don't know if that number is a max or min.  I don't know what your using the output for, and if this detail might not be a concern, as such you can just ignore my comments.  I've only mentioned it as it just seems odd too me, but might be totally logical to what your doing. :)

Comment: Yes, the requirement here is to show only the ranges and numbers without those keys as are managed in another way in a different part. 
Without considering later if that a min or max as it is aggregate in the right place later.

Comment: @Keith you were right about the min and max actually that was changed now (not from me but colleagues) that min and max cannot be never separated so the case of having only max and min is not more valid. 
Now will be always a range 
min: 0 max: 10 or min: 10 max: 100
Never
min: 100 max: 0 as this will be an error
will update the question with the new info

Comment: @Jakub  Oh, nice one.  Thought something wasn't 100%.  I believe all the answers here should still work, and with that new rule could be slightly simplified..

Comment: what do oyu mean by *"will give an error"*? where? how? or an exception?

Comment: @NinaScholz is a step before criteria by a validator functionality not included here.
It is a method that creates that criteria object with some conditions.
I included the final data after that process as the validator is not the scope of the question. Pratically if the values are wrong the condition throws an error as invalid data in that step before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this in several steps:

- get `criteria`, default to an empty object `{}`
- get `max, min` in `criteria`, exclude the falsy values (i.e. null, false, empty string)
- join the range by `-`
- exclude falsy values
- map and get the final result

```js
const res = [
  { criteria: { min: "25", max: "100" } },
  { criteria: { max: "85" } },
  { criteria: { min: "10" } },
  { criteria: { max: "100", min: "" } },
  { criteria: { max: "", min: "" } },
  { criteria: null },
]
  .map(({ criteria }) => criteria || {})
  .map(({ min, max }) => [min, max].filter(Boolean))
  .map(arrOfMinMax => arrOfMinMax.join(" - "))
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(valid => ({ valid: [valid] }))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concat with a [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```js
const
    data = [{ criteria: { min: "25", max: "100" } }, { criteria: { max: "85" } }, { criteria: { min: "10" } }, { criteria: {} }],
    result = data.map(({ criteria: { min, max } = {} }) => ({ valid: []
        .concat(min ?? [], max ?? [])
        .join(' - ') || null
    }));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you are half way there

```js
const res = [{
  criteria: {
    min: "25",
    max: "100"
  }
}, {
  criteria: {
    max: "85"
  }
  },
  {
  criteria: {
    min: "10"
  }
  }, {criteria: null}, {}
].map(obj => {
if (!obj || !obj.criteria) {
  return {valid: null}
} 

const {min, max} = obj.criteria
if (min && max) {
   return {valid: [`${min} - ${max}`]}
} 
return {valid: [min || max]}
 })


console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is nice but is not considering we can have criteria: null when that happen will be valid: null

Comment: @Jakub updated to cater for null

Answer (score 0):

More convenient way , would be using a traditional for loop, instead of map;
you can try the below sample.

```
const res = [
   {
        criteria: {
            min: "25",
            max: "100"
        }
   }, 
   {
        criteria: {
            max: "85"
       },
   },
   {
       criteria: {
           min: "10"
       },
   }, 
       {
       criteria: null
   }, 

]

let arr = new Array();

for(let i = 0; i< res.length; i++ ){
   if (res[i].criteria === null) continue;
   let min = res[i].criteria.min, max = res[i].criteria.max;
   const str = min && max ? `${min} - ${max}` : min ? min : max ? max : ''
   const objWithMaxMin = {
       valid: [str]
   }
   arr.push(objWithMaxMin)
}

console.log(arr)
```